# Any command I enter ends with Extra junk after value. Why?

Tags: 14.10

Super noob here using 14.10.  When I try to do anything via command line, the response is always something like:

```
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf:4: Extra junk after value
```

All I want to do is download VLC and Popcorn Time.

To install VLC I attempted:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

after i tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf:4: Extra junk after value
```

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` file content:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf 
// Pre-configure all packages with debconf before they are installed. 
// If you don't like it, comment it out. 
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};
apt::cache-limit "100000000" APT::Cache-Limit "100000000"; 
$ sudo apt-get update 
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf:4: Extra junk after value
```

Comment: you're more likely to get a useful answer if you provide more details about what generates the error. what command(s) were you trying to run?

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/660409/edit) your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf`

Comment: Did you try to edit 70debconf ?

Comment: Just tried this:

morgan@morgan-Satellite-A660:~$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
// Pre-configure all packages with debconf before they are installed.
// If you don't like it, comment it out.
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};apt::cache-limit "100000000"
APT::Cache-Limit "100000000";

morgan@morgan-Satellite-A660:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf:4: Extra junk after value

Answer (score 2):

Where you trying to increase the cache size?

Open your `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` file in your favorite text editor:

> `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf`

and add a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of the line:

```
APT::Cache-Limit "100000000"
```

to make it look like:

```
APT::Cache-Limit "100000000";
```

---

All in one

```
// Pre-configure all packages with debconf before they are installed. 
// If you don't like it, comment it out. 
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};
APT::Cache-Limit "100000000";
```

---

You can delete the `apt::cache-limit "100000000"` line because `APT::Cache-Limit "100000000";` is the correct format.

From `man apt-conf`:

> APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";The trailing semicolon is required and the
>   quotes are optional.

Comment: I think it is better to delete the last line.

Comment: @dedunumax you mean delete `apt::cache-limit "100000000"`, right?

Comment: Yeah last line. I am using ubuntu 14.04. I have only first three lines in my 70debconf file.

Comment: @dedunumax Yes, the main problem is the lack of `;`. I guess OP was playing around with the file and forgot to delete the unformatted line.

Comment: so i found the file, ron, should it now look like this DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};apt::cache-limit "100000000"; and i guess my next question is now what? i'm sorry i suck so much. gotta learn somehow!

Comment: @hoosierhickey do you want to set cache-limit?

Comment: @dedunmax i really am not sure. i just want to be able to download stuff through the terminal but it won't let me.

Comment: @hoosierhickey did you edit your file as above?